# Issue pushing objects into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a piece of code that takes an object and pushes it onto the back of a vector, but the objects are not being pushed correctly.

I am writing an OpenGL application and I want to draw many lines in it. In order to store those lines, I first create each line in a `C2DPointSet` and when I stop drawing, I want to push the current line in my vector of lines. By debugging the code, I saw that the length of the vector after pushing the line is 0 and the same line in the vector has 0 points (which should not be the case). Here is the code:

```
vector <C2DPointSet> lines; //global variables
C2DPointSet line;

//function that runs if a button is pressed and i click in my glwindow
void lineButtonFunction(int x,int y){
    C2DPoint currentPoint;  
    currentPoint=workspacePoint(x,y);//returns point;s cordinates acording to cursorx,y-it works
    line.AddCopy(currentPoint);//adds a copy of the given point to obj line
}


//code that runs when i am done drawing 
if(buttons[i].getButtonText()=='L'){ 
    lines.push_back(line);
    line.DeleteAll();//empties the obj
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. With different objects the code would run. I am not sure, but i think that the problem stems from pushing `C2DPointSet` because it stores as many points as I like. Also, I observed that regardless of how many points I stored in the line I got its size as 12.

`C2DPoints` and `C2DPointSet` are from geolib; information can be found [here](http://www.geolib.co.uk/doxygen/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it depends on the contents of C2DPointSet class. Possible that you don't have copy constructor there. My suggestion is to have a vector of references instead of vector of actual objects. That way you will also minimize the overhead. So you should have vector<&C2DPointSet> lines, instead of what you have. Try it. It might work.

Comment: @FredOverflow you may be right. Then just a vector of pointers (e.g. std::vector<C2DPointSet*> lines.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that [C2DPointSet](http://www.geolib.co.uk/doxygen/class_c2_d_point_set.html) has a constructor and a destructor, but no copy constructor and copy assignment operator, i.e. C2DPointSet does not follow [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/). This is problematic if C2DPointSet has pointer members. Does it? Then it is inherently broken. It just won't work in vectors.